# Notation for dependent function type

Tags: notation, type-theory

Very often (really, very often), when declaring the type of a function, I find the common mathematical notation lacking. And I wish for a way to express the type more precisely.

Assume we have some set $X$, and there is some function $f$ that takes a (non-empty) subset of $X$ and maps it to an element of that subset.
Using common notation, we could introduce $f$ as $f \colon 2^X \to X$.
But we know more! We know that the application of $f$ must return an element of the argument.

Using some made-up notation, we could write $f \colon (A \colon 2^X) \to A$, giving the name $A$ to the argument of the function, and reusing it as the type of the codomain.

So the questions are:

1. Is there some accepted convention for expressing these dependent types?
2. Assuming not, is the proposed notation readable and intuitive? Personally, I find it confusing, as it looks a bit like $f\colon A \to A$.

Comment: How about if you write $f:2^X\to X$ with $X\supset A\mapsto f(A)\in A$?

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Yes, formulating additional constraints is one way of achieving the same result. I think in this case, stating simply "$f(A) \in A$ for all $A$" would be clearer.

Comment: I have also used this notation, or rather $f \colon (A \in 2^X) \to A$ when it's not about type, for my own notes. I wouldn't hesitate to introduce it if I were ever to write a paper where it's useful (which I will probably never do).

Comment: I have actually seen the notation in dependent type theory, e.g. $\mathsf{id} : (A : \mathsf{Type}) \to A \to A$.

Comment: @md2perpe, that's terrible notation though. The codomain of $\mathrm{id}$ appears to be $A \rightarrow A$. So I guess it can be composed with arrows whose domain is $A \rightarrow A$. That is, we're looking for arrows of type $(A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow X$. But there *are* no such arrows, because we haven't told the reader what kind of a thing $A$ is.

Comment: @goblin. The codomain of $\mathsf{id}$ *is* $A \to A$, but the codomain of $\mathsf{id}(A)$ is $A$. Don't confuse $\mathsf{id}$ with $\mathrm{id}$. We have $\mathsf{id}(A) \sim \mathrm{id}_A$. One can modify the notation to mark that $A$ is not in the "real" domain and may not be given as an explicit argument to a call of the function but be automatically derived by the compiler: $\mathsf{id} : (\overline{A : \mathsf{Type}}) \to A \to A$ or $\mathsf{id} : (A : \mathsf{Type}) \Rightarrow A \to A$.

Comment: @goblin. On top of p. 5 (unnumbered pages) of http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf you can see `identity : (A : Set) -> A -> A`.

Comment: @md2perpe, whether we denote it $\mathrm{id}$ or $\mathsf{id}$, my point remains, which is that no function has domain $A \rightarrow A$, because we haven't told the reader what $A$ is. Which is why I consider this bad notation.

Comment: @goblin. We *do* tell the reader what $A$ is when first applying $\mathsf{id}$ to some type: $\mathsf{id}(\mathsf{Int}) : \mathsf{Int} \to \mathsf{Int}$.

Comment: @md2perpe, yes, sure. If we're willing to focus on evaluation like that we can get it to work. This is no surprise really; we're basically interpreting $f : (x:X) \rightarrow Y_x$ to mean $f : \prod_{x:X} Y_x$. But supposing we don't want to think in terms of evaluation. Suppose we're category theorists, and we think in terms of function composition. A "function" of the form $f : (x:X) \rightarrow Y_x$ doesn't have any meaningful way of being composed with a function of the form $g : Y_x \rightarrow Z$ as far as I can see, because we don't know what $x$ is. So....

Comment: ... if we're thinking categorically, and for myself at least, that's basically what the arrow suggests, I think we're better off putting the $x:X$ elsewhere. For example, we could write $$f : 1 \xrightarrow{x:X} Y_x, \qquad g : Y_x \xrightarrow{x:X} Z,$$ which can be composed to obtain $$g\circ f : 1 \xrightarrow{x:X} Z.$$ I find this a lot more satisfying, because we haven't thrown function composition out the window.

Comment: Another possible notation would be: $$\frac{x\in X \vdash f : 1 \rightarrow Y_x \qquad x\in X \vdash g : Y_x \rightarrow Z}{x \in X \vdash g\circ f : 1 \rightarrow Z}.$$ Whatever we choose, we should make sure that function composition continues to work correctly imvho.

Comment: @goblin. We aren't even allowed to write $f : (x:X) \to Y_x$ since $Y$ hasn't been introduced before it's used. We should write $f : (X : \mathsf{Type}) \to (x : X) \to (Y : X \to \mathsf{Type}) \to Y(x)$.

Comment: @md2perpe, sorry, I meant to imply that $X$ was a fixed but arbitrary type, not a variable. So for example, let $X = \mathsf{Int}$ for concreteness. That was sloppy of me.

Comment: @goblin. Is $Y$ also supposed to be a fixed (named/global) type-valued function? Let me then use sans-serif style: $\mathsf{X}$. In that case we can write $f : (x : \mathsf{X}) \to \mathsf{Y}(x)$ and if $g : (x : \mathsf{X}) \to \mathsf{Y}(x) \to \mathsf{Z}$ then we cannot compose these directly, but have to "lambda" on $x$: 
$$h : (x : \mathsf{X}) \to (f(x)(g(x)(y)) : \mathsf{Z})$$

Comment: @md2perpe, yes, that's what I mean. We cannot compose them directly. For me, this suggests we shouldn't use the $\rightarrow$ notation in the way you're describing. As I'm sure you know, in category theory, we distinguish between a morphism $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ and it's representation $1 \xrightarrow{f} [X,Y]$ as an element of an object. Since the domains/codomains are different, it's better to think of them as different entities. I don't mind upgrading the notation $[X,Y]$ to allow us to write $[x:X,Y_x]$ in place of $\prod_{x:X}Y_x$, but imvho we should leave the arrow notation alone.

Comment: @goblin. Still, it's not because of the notation with dependent types but because of the types not directly matching. We cannot compose $f : \mathsf{X} \to \mathsf{Y} \to \mathsf{Z}$ and $g : \mathsf{Z} \to \mathsf{W}$ directly either; we need to do $(\lambda x) (\lambda y) g(f(x)(y)) : \mathsf{W}$.

Comment: @goblin. And I noted that my formula for $h$ above is wrong. Of course it should be
$$h : (x : \mathsf{X}) \to (g(x)(f(x)) : \mathsf{Z})$$

Comment: @goblin. I didn't know about category theory distinguishing between a morphism and its representation. I haven't studied category theory, just read some online.

Comment: I can also mention another notation: $\mathsf{id} : \forall(A : \mathsf{Type}) (A \to A)$ meaning that for any type $A$, $\mathsf{id}$ maps from $A$ to $A$, i.e. $\forall(A : \mathsf{Type}) (\mathsf{id} : A \to A)$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're basically looking for the notations $$\sum_{x \in X} Y_x \qquad \prod_{x \in X} Y_x.$$ The former means the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \in X$ and $y \in Y_x$. The latter means the set of all ways of assigning to each element $x \in X$ a corresponding element of $Y_x$.

For example, a function $f$ that maps each non-empty subset of $X$ to an element of that subset could be denoted $$f \in \prod_{A\in \mathcal{P}_{\neq 0}(X)}A.$$

Some people would call this "type theory", but really it's just set theory.

Comment: To give a more formal set-theoretic rendition of possible definitions of these (basically your 2nd and 3rd sentence in symbols): $\sum_{x\in X}Y_x\equiv\{(x,y)\mid x\in X\land y\in Y_x\}$ and, $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x\equiv\{f\mid f:X\to\bigcup_{x\in X}Y_x\land\forall x.x\in X\Rightarrow f(x)\in Y_x\}$ where $f:A\to B$ abbreviates that $f\subseteq A\times B$ is a functional relation or more directly, $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x\equiv\{f\mid(\forall t.t\in f\Rightarrow\exists x,y.x\in X\land y\in Y_x\land t=(x,y))\land\forall x.x\in X\Rightarrow\exists y.(x,y)\in f\land\forall z.(x,z)\in f\Rightarrow y=z\}$.

Comment: I've never seen these notations before. How do they (esp. the second one) relate to the $Y^X$ notation for functions, which also stems from the function item being a product/ordered tuple?

Comment: @ziggystar This notation (or minor variations of it) is extremely common in [dependent type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), particularly Martin-Löf type theory. They are often primitive notions in such systems. The function type $Y^X$ is often *defined* in such systems as $\prod_{x:X}Y$, i.e. as the special case where the bound variable $x$ does not occur in $Y$. (Similarly, $X\times Y$ is defined as $\sum_{x:X}Y$.) In set theory, we normally describe $\prod_{x\in X}Y_x$ as "$Y$ is an $X$-indexed family of sets".

Comment: @Derek I think I got it. Because you make the $Y_X$ in $\prod_{x\in X}Y_X$ $X$-indexed, you achieve a dependence between the argument and the respective codomain, i.e., you can have a different codomain for every $X$. Is this correct?

Comment: @ziggystar, that's correct, if by $Y_X$ you mean $Y_x$, and by "for every $X$" you mean "for every $x \in X$."

Answer (score 1):

If this type of functions occurs many times in your context you can say the following:

Given a family ${\cal F}$ of nonempty subsets of $X$ a function $f:\>{\cal F}\to X$ satisfying $f(A)\in A$ for all $A\in{\cal F}$ is called a *choice function*.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical writing, it's not common to think properties like the one you describe as part of the type of the function. The notation $f:Y\to Z$ is essentially only used to denote the domain and codomain of a function (or perhaps a "partial function"), not any extra information.

If the input must be a nonempty subset, and you haven't made it abundantly clear that you're allowing partial functions, then you can't write $f:2^X\to X$ since that would allow an empty subset as an input.

Depending on what you want to do with functions of this sort, one way to express your idea in mathematical language might be something like:
"Let $f:2^X-\{\emptyset\}\to X$ satisfy $f(A)\in A$ for all $A\in2^X-\{\emptyset\}$."

There are many notational/wording variants, but that should give you some ideas/help you narrow down what you'd like to say.

Comment: That's the answer I expected, but didn't wish for. :)

Comment: If the downvoter has any concerns about my answer, I'd be happy to try to address them. Feel free to contact me privately through the contact in my profile if you'd rather not comment publicly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on goblin's answer, its comments, and my recent experience.

### Product Notation

A function $f \colon A \to B$ is a way of assigning to each element of $A$ (the domain) an element of $B$ (the codomain).
We can also think of this function as a subset of tuples $f \subseteq A \times B$ that has the property that each element of $A$ occurs exactly once as a first (left) entry. Using $\prod$ as quantifier for (cartesian) product, we can write this as

$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} \{a\} \times B,$$

or using index notation

$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a.$$

With this notation, we can formulate more precise codomains for each $a$, e.g., for the general case where $C \colon A \to 2^B$ maps each $a$ to a subset of $B$
$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} C(a)_a,$$
which is more precise than stating $f \colon A \to B$.

### Indexed Families

[Indexed Families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) are basically the same as the above product notation — simply using a different notation.
Using an indexed family, we can write
$$f = (B_a)_{a \in A},$$
which means the same as
$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a.$$
Note how both notations contain the same information: $a \in A$ and $B_a$.

When using an indexed family, function application is usually written as $f_a$ instead of $f(a)$, but as both mean the same thing, they are formally interchangeable. Although this might be unexpected for some readers.

### Exponential Function Notation As Special Case

Starting from the product notation
$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a,$$
we can remove the index $a$, if the codomain does not depend on the concrete value of $a$:
$$f \in \prod_{a \in A} B.$$
If we rewrite above product in exponential form, we arrive at the (more or less) common exponential function notation
$$f \in B^A.$$